# Dreamweaver CS5 Live View not displaying ajax results after first load

Tags: jquery, json, dreamweaver

I'm new to Dreamweaver CS5.  I have a HTML5 website that's using jQuery to retrieve JSON data and render the results in a UL.  The very first time I open Index.html page and load it in the live view, i can see the results of the ajax call.  Subsequent refreshes of the live view does not display any data.  I have to close the file, re-open it to see my rendered JSON data.  Then it follows the same pattern where subsequent refreshes show no data.  It seems like a setting needs to be tripped, but I'm not sure what to do.  Thanks for your help.